# How to calculate percentage change with zero in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-science-experience

I want to calculate the percentage change for the following data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                   'points': [12, 0, 19, 22, 0, 25, 0, 30],
                   'score': [12, 0, 19, 22, 0, 25, 0, 30] 
                   
                   })
print(df)
```

When I applied this step, it returns inf which is obvious because we are dividing by zero.

```
df['score'] = df.groupby('team', sort=False)['score'].apply(
     lambda x: x.pct_change()).to_numpy()
```

But if we see in each column the change from 0 to 19 the change is 100%, from 0 to 25 the change is 100%, and from 0 to 30 the change is 100%. So, I was wondering how can I calculate those values.

current result
[image]

Expected result is
[image]

Comment: Do you mean diff?

Comment: No, I want to calculate the percentage change between two rows.

Comment: This is not an percentage change

Comment: I am sorry I thought that was a percentage change. Then what it is?

Comment: You should update your example to add an actual case where the % change is not NaN/0/inf. The current 1/-1 only output is quite confusing.

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to replace the infinite values with 1?

```
import numpy as np

df[['points', 'score']] = (
  df.groupby('team')
    .pct_change()
    .replace(np.inf, 1)
)
```

Output:

```
  team  points  score
0    A     NaN    NaN
1    A    -1.0   -1.0
2    A     1.0    1.0
3    B     NaN    NaN
4    B    -1.0   -1.0
5    B     1.0    1.0
6    C     NaN    NaN
7    C     1.0    1.0
```

Comment: But I want the first column as well, how to do that?

Comment: Do you want to modify the original DataFrame? Or a new one?

Comment: this is not the result I wanted. I want to calculate the percentage change between two rows but when the denominator is zero, it is giving me a problem. So, when the denominator is zero, I want to show a 100% increase or 1

Comment: Sorry but the question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question. Would you mind reviewing the question? If I use sign and take the difference between 12 and 11, it will return -1, which is wrong

Comment: Also replacing with 100% when the denominator is 0 is meaningless. For example a change from 0 to 5 would be 100% but 0.001 to 5 would be 5000%

Comment: yeah but I have only integer value, not the decimal value.

Comment: See if the update gives you what you want

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to count the drops in score as a negative, but this will give you the calculation you're looking for (multiplying by 100 to get to how you're representing the percentages in your output). Basically, diff calculates the difference between current and prior.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
               'points': [12, 0, 19, 22, 0, 25, 0, 30],
               'score': [12, 0, 19, 22, 0, 25, 0, 30]

               })

df["score"] = df.groupby('team', sort=False)['score'].diff() * 100

print(df)
```

To set the rows to 1 / -1, simply use loc for positive / negative values and set accordingly like so

```
df.loc[df["score"] < 0, "score"] = -1
df.loc[df["score"] > 0, "score"] = 1
```

Comment: Can I replace those 1900, 2500, and 3000 with 1 or 100? I think when it dropped from 12 to 0, it dropped by 100 % and when it rise from 0 to 19 it increased by 100%

Comment: I have changed the expected result in the question

Comment: @BadCoder - I've updated the answer to show how you can set to 1 / -1 (you can change it to 100 / -100 or whatever else you wish)

Answer (score 0):

```
# take the sign using np.sign for the diff b/w two consecutive rows
df['chg']=np.sign(df.groupby('team')['score'].diff())
df
```

```
    team    points  score   chg
0     A        12      12   NaN
1     A         0       0   -1.0
2     A        19      19   1.0
3     B        22      22   NaN
4     B         0       0   -1.0
5     B        25      25   1.0
6     C         0       0   NaN
7     C        30      30   1.0
```

Comment: If I use sign, and take the difference between 12 and 11, it will return -1, which is wrong

Comment: @BadCoder, this answer matches the expected result. Please update the expected result if it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

We need to be careful to avoid division by zero errors when there are 0s in the second column. To do this, we use the `replace` method to replace any 0s with 1s before performing the calculation.

```py
df['percent_change'] = ((df['col_2'] - df['col_1']) / df['col_2'].replace(0, 1)) * 100
```